# The value is not set after POST if use asp-for attribute in MVC Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple view model:

```
public class GogViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public bool IsBeta { get; set; }

  public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

and controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
  return View(new GogViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index(GogViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.Result = DoSomething();
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

and View:

```
@model GogViewModel
<div>
  <form method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" asp-for="Name">Release name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name" placeholder="paste release name here" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" asp-for="Result">Result</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Result" />
         <p>@Model.Result</p> <!-- it works here means the value is printed -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info copy float-right" data-target="Result"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Fix it" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Somehow the result is not output after POST request.

Why ? Where's my mistake ?

Comment: looks ok double check what DoSomething(); is returning, and ensure its not returning "" or null

Comment: It returns value, I checked with debug

Comment: as in you could place with,`  model.Result = "value"` for testing...

Comment: I tested all scenarios...If I use `p` tag, it display nice, if use `input` / `textarea` doesn't

Comment: try `if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.Result = "in side is valid"
  }
  model.Result = "out side is valid"
  return View(model);`

Comment: just to be clear are u saying `<p>@Model.Result</p>` works but `<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Result" />` is not doing what your expecting

Comment: odd checked against my own code doing simular things and mine works, maybe Result is a reserved word... try rename it to MyResult

Comment: @Seabizkit exactly, works for p/div/span but not if use input/textarea

Comment: in Startup.cs do you have `services.AddRazorPages` you probably do just trying to rule out werid stuff. remove data-target="Result" and see if that helps dont know what that is

Comment: Yes I have `services.AddRazorPages` in `Startup.cs`

Comment: take `type="text"` out so mine is `<input  asp-for="SourceName" class="form-control-plaintext"  />` and it works

Comment: did it work? or did you find the answer to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work in the following way:

1. Set private setter to `Result` property => `public string Result {get; private set;}`
2. Add method which set value for Result: `internal void SetResult(string result) { Result = result; }`
3. In controller, call `SetResult` like: `model.SetResult(...);`

and will display in readonly input. I don't know why it works and I don't understand why the value is cleared when put it on input.

I used input with readonly attribute in order to copy to clipboard the output value with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add something in the input tag like value="@Model.Result"?

Comment: also thought it may be this.... but i checked against my own code, it should work the way  it is